# Next Sitecore Brazil User Group - SUGBR session

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Date/Time EST: Tuesday, November 21, 2017, Starts at 4:00 PM

Date/Time UTC: Tuesday, November 21, 2017, Starts at 9:00 PM

Location: Plaza Victória Business Center
Servidão Recanto Verde, 155 - Business Center, Florianópolis

RSVP: https://www.meetup.com/SUG-BR/events/244864927/?eventId=244864927

Join us @Florianopolis, Tuesday Nov 21th, for our next Brazil Sitecore User Group(SUGBR). On this session both Sitecore MVPs Diego Moretto and Rodrigo Peplau will be performing a recap on Sitecore Symposiom 2017, Sitecore 9 and so much more.